# Get the image from Google Feeds API

Tags: javascript, html, rss, google-api

I know this is likely very easy however I have been bashing my head for little over an hour and I am stuck.

I am trying to use Google Feed API to show a list of recent houses, It works just fine until it comes to pulling the image. I am struggling to get it to pull the image. I am sure there is a way because the slideshow script that google released can get the images...

Here's my code taken from a basic example I am absolutely clueless as to where to go to even try and figure out how to retrieve the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

<title>Google Feed Loader Example #1</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=#"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("feeds", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(showFeed);

function showFeed() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.trulia.com/rss2/San_Francisco,CA/3p_baths/3p_beds/800000-2000000_price/date;d_sort/");
  feed.setNumEntries(10);
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("headlines");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var bmfx = result.feed.entries[i].mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = '<h3><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a> <cite>by ' + entry.mediaGroup + '</cite></h3>';
        li.innerHTML += '<p>' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p>';
        container.appendChild(li);
      }
    } else {
        var container = document.getElementById("headlines");
        container.innerHTML = '<li>Ooops It Failed';
    }
  });
}
</script>

</head> 

<body>  
<h1>Google Feed Loader Example</h1>
<ul id="headlines"></ul> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your case, you should use:

```
var bmfx = entry.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url;
```

Comment: Agh thank you, I did something very similar just was a little off. You are correct, once again thank you very much.